# First time donor report

Tags: civicontribute, reports

I am trying to pull a first time donor report. I am using the Repeat Contributions report. I set the Initial Date Range as custom from beginning to Dec 31, 2016. The Second Date Range is This Year. I set Range 1 Amount as Less than 1 and the Range 2 Amount as Greater than 1. It shows 0 results. I tried several different combos (Is not Null/Is null, etc). All combos I tried either show 0 or they show all donors. Can I use this report to show first time donors? Those that did not give in the previous period but gave in this period.

ps. I know that I have new donors, so with the right polling, I should see results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a way to specifically run a "First Time Donors" report, though it's a little hidden.

- Go to **Reports menu » Contribution Reports**.
- Select "Contribution Details Report".
- Under the "Filters" tab, set "Contribution Ordinality" to "First by Contributor" to only show first-time donors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. This is what I was looking for. As you said, it is not very obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to get the [Summary Fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) extension. That calculates fields like 'Date of First Contribution' which are very helpful for such reporting

---